# Use C++ DLL callback function in a Delphi application

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, callback

I try to use C++ DLL function in my Delphi application. I've the problem in using call back function like that:

**Exported functions definitions in C++:**

```
typedef void (__CDECL__* RegisterCallBacksFunction)(AudioChunkCallBackFunction, CaptureEventCallBackFunction, LogMngr*);
```

**Callback definitions:**

```
typedef void (__CDECL__*AudioChunkCallBackFunction)(AudioChunkRef, CStdString& capturePort);
typedef void (__CDECL__*CaptureEventCallBackFunction)(CaptureEventRef, CStdString& capturePort);
```

**AudioChunkRef and CaptureEventRef :**

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<AudioChunk> AudioChunkRef;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<CaptureEvent> CaptureEventRef;
```

**And AudioChunk and CaptureEvent are C++ class:**

```
class __declspec( dllexport ) AudioChunk // or CaptureEvent (both are similar)
{
public:
//some functions and variables
private:
//some functions and variables
};
```

**C++ library exports:**

```
extern "C"
{
__declspec( dllexport ) void __CDECL__  RegisterCallBacks(AudioChunkCallBackFunction, CaptureEventCallBackFunction, LogMngr*);
}
```

How can use RegisterCallBacks function in my Delphi app. ?

Comment: See Rudy's Delphi corner for how to flatten a C++ object interface, [articles-cppobjs](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html)

Comment: @LURD I'm no C++ expert, but I suspect that the `boost` kind of objects are also a particular type of C++ class, which may require additional management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you can not import C++ classes directly to map Delphi classes. That is, even if you get a pointer to a `AudioChunk` instance, you won't be able to access it directly from Delphi. So use of your callbacks won't be possible directly.

So you'll have to define by hand a ["flat" C interface](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html) to be imported in Delphi, which will implement the callback in C++, then expose the interface as C functions, with parameters as C `struct` instead of C++ *boost* classes.

Comment: Once you've done this then you'll also have to find interop friendly alternatives for `CStdString`, `AudioChunkRef` etc.

Comment: Thanks LU RD for the great Rudy's article link.

Comment: I was hoping for XE2 to bring some sort of objects conformity between Builder C++ and Delphi. At least I thought I read that somewhere, but maybe it was a dream only.

Answer (score 1):

The naming conventions of different languages (like a Pascal and C++) is very complicated topic. At least C++ doesn't grant that migration from one vendor to another will keep same export name for particular methods. For example: `Eleven@SomeClass@@QAEHXZ` - is declaration of `int SomeClass::Eleven()` for MSVC. The only workable way - is C declaration, using `extern "C"` granted by standard conventions.

But what about classes? To avoid wheel reinvention - for case Delphi-C++ use OLE/COM, in general you will declare interface and could be able to do the same on both sides.

Comment: COM is a simple but not easy to deploy solution. You'll have to register each COM object on every PC (or do it by code, which is not easy any more); you'll have security issues if you run them over a network; you may face interface mismatch when your COM object is updated; you'll have problems to share `struct` as `record` (the `VT_RECORD` type is not handled by Delphi, so you'll have to use interfaces); it is a Windows-only solution... But despite all its difficulties, it may be a quick to implement solution, with good performance. +1 for COM.

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez - wow how many problems are there! But not at all. For simplest level (that should be applied by @SimaWB ) COM is just a contract how to declare interfaces and them implementation. What is needed there - (1) declare COM-like implementation on C++ side (2) declare stub on Pascal-side (3) provide own `extern "C"` like function to create class instance - and resolve it at Pascal side. That's all.

Comment: You are perfectly right. Creating the class instance in the C++ code will resolve a lot of issues related to registering the COM class system-wide. It is not they way I use it mostly - because I use COM to work with .Net code, and here we speak about unmanaged C++ code. My mistake. :)